# Customize a response after calling the backend

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there is a way to customize the response after calling the backend server like I need to mask a card number before reply to the client the calling my wso2 API

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use message mediation on Out flow / Response. Depending of version API Manager you use, read this doc: API manager 2.6.0 [Adding Mediation Extensions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions). In this old version it is described *Out flow*
In the latest documentation: [Creating Per-API Mediation Policies](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/#creating-per-api-mediation-policies) it is in Runtime Configuration / Response / Message Mediation.

Then you can design the custom mediation policy using the tooling support provided by WSO2 Integration Studio.

Comment: I followed the 2 links but I am using APIM version 4.0.0 and need to change the response of an API

Comment: Is there anyway to make it without use WSO2 Integration Studio. ?

Comment: Yes, you can use any text editor, to prepare manually that custom policy, like is described here: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/#creating-manually-and-saving-in-the-file-system

Comment: Yes sure but the case is that I don't know how to apply my requirements which is to change the value of a JSON property from the JSON response that comes back from my backend layer

Answer (score 0):

Just you can modify your payload using payload factory meidator in your out sequence you can see an example below i have masked the value of cardnumber as *******.

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="json">  
       <format>{ "ProfileId": { "source": "SALESFORCE", "cardnumber": "**********" },  "Name": "$2", "Username": "$3", "LastName":  "$4", "Email": "$5"  }</format>  
       <args>  
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:cardnumber"/>  
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Name"/>  
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Username"/>  
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:LastName"/>  
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Email"/>  
       </args>  
      </payloadFactory>
```

[1] https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/payloadFactory-Mediator/

Comment: That works but it does feel kinda pointless to still reference the cardnumber in an arg as it's not used at all. I'd recommend removing that one to limit exposure of the card number to more mediators.

Comment: Actually, I am using API Manager version 4.0.0

Comment: still you can create a per API mediation sequence manually and upload it from the API Publisher itself. You can follow the attached documentation. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/